# Get session proxy bean in JSP

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have a session bean like this:

```
@Component
@Scope(value="session", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class MySession  { ... }
```

How can I enable access to this bean in JSP?

I displayed session data in JSP and I got this:

```
org.springframework.web.context.request.ServletRequestAttributes.DESTRUCTION_CALLBACK.scopedTarget.mySession
scopedTarget.mySession
```

So, I tried using `${scopedTarget.mySession.qualites}`, but it didn't work.

Comment: Try `${sessionScope['scopedTarget.mySession'].qualites}`

Answer (score 0):

If you expose spring beans as context properties using this view resolver configuration, then it should be possible to access the bean with a value expression such as #{mySession.qualites} directly:

```
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="exposeContextBeansAsAttributes" value="true"/>
</bean>
```

As an alternative, expose the spring bean to the view model, by using in the @Controller the [@ModelAttribute](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-modelattrib) annotation.

Comment: Thanks @jhadesdev No i don't want to expose every bean i have.

Comment: in that case the @ModelAttribute allows to expose beans selectivelly

Comment: No but i want use `@Component
@Scope(value="session", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)` i think just somthing is missing because  i read this is some of the way to store data in session ?

Comment: i want store in session not in request like with @ModelAttribute